# Cumulative style calculations of entries in a data table using class initialisation in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to determine the optimum value of Z in a data table using Python. The optimum of Z occurs when the difference in Y values is greater than 10. In my code I am assigning the elements of each entry into a class. In order to determine the optimum I therefore need to access the previously calculated value of Y and subtract it from the new value. This all seems very cumbersome to me so if you know of a better way I can perform these type of calculations please let me know. My sample data table is:

```
X       Y       Z

1       5       10
2       3       20
3       4       30
4       6       40
5       12      50
6       12      60
7       34      70
8       5       80
```

My code so far is:

```
class values:                                      
    def __init__(self, X, Y, Z): 

        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.Z = Z  

        #Diff = Y2 - Y1

        #if Diff > 10:
            #optimum = Z
        #else:
            #pass

        #optimum 

valueLst = []

f = open('sample.txt','r')


for i in f:
    X = i.split('\t')[0]
    Y = i.split('\t')[1]
    Z = i.split('\t')[2]

    x = values(X,Y,Z)

valueLst.append(x)
```

An example of the operation I would like to achieve is shown in the following table. The difference in Y values is calculated in the third column, I would like to return value of Z when the difference is 22 i.e. Z value of 70.

```
1       2               10
2       3       1       20
3       4       1       30
4       6       2       40
5       12      6       50
6       12      0       60
7       34      22      70
8       35      1       80
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `class` seems like overkill for this.  Why not a list of `(x, y, z)` tuples?

```
valueLst = []
for i in f:
    valueLst.append(tuple(i.split('\t')))
```

You can then determine the differences between the `y` values and get the last item `z` from the 3-tuple corresponding to the largest delta-`y`:

```
yDiffs = [0] + list(valueLst[i][1] - valueLst[i-1][1]
                    for i in range(1, len(valueLst)))
bestZVal = valueLst[yDiffs.index(max(yDiffs))][2]
```

Comment: Use `Value = collections.namedtuple('Value', 'x y z')` if you really must have a class for storing your XYZ tuples, but I don't see a huge benefit in using a `namedtuple` over a `tuple` here.

Comment: Using tuple of tuples in this case is unreadable; _nameduple_ here adds unnecessary reference overhead.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks so much for this. The table I am working with is much larger (around 1000 rows across 6 columns) in your opinion would this be the most efficient way of processing large data sets like this?

Comment: 1000*6 isn't much in the scheme of things , I would expect this process to take negligible time to find the appropriate `z`

Answer (score 0):

To start, you can put the columns into a list data structure:

```
f = open('sample.txt','r')

x, y, z = [], [], []
for i in f:
    ix, iy, iz = map(int, i.split('\t')) # the map function changes each number
                                         # to an integer from a string
    y.append(iy)
    z.append(iz)
```

When you have data structures, you can use them together to get other data structures you want.

Then you can get each difference starting from the second y:

```
differences  = [y[i] - y[i+1] for i in range(1,len(y))]
```

What you want is the z at the same index as the max of the differences, so:

```
maxIndex = y.index(max(differences))
answer = z[maxIndex]
```

Comment: Instead of `differences  = [y[i] - y[i+1] for i in range(1,len(y))]`, use the `itertools pairwise` recipe from http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes. This code becomes `differences = [a-b for a,b in pairwise(y)]` (or go functional crazy with `imap(operator.subtract, pairwise(y))`)

Comment: when you need element and index - use _enumerate_; using range to iterate over list is extremely un-pythonic

Answer (score 0):

Given a file with this content:

```
1       5       10
2       3       20
3       4       30
4       6       40
5       12      50
6       12      60
7       34      70
8       5       80
```

You can read the file and convert to a list of tuples like so:

```
data=[]
with open('value_list.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        x,y,z=map(int,line.split())
        data.append((x,y,z))

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 5, 10), (2, 3, 20), (3, 4, 30), (4, 6, 40), (5, 12, 50), (6, 12, 60), (7, 34, 70), (8, 5, 80)]
```

Then you can use that data to find tuples that meet your criteria using a list comprehension. In this case `y-previous y>10`:

```
tgt=10     
print([data[i][2]  for i in range(1,len(data)) if data[i][1]-data[i-1][1]>tgt])
[70]
```

Comment: They're not looking for the difference between `x` and `y`, but between this `y` and the previous line's `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Skipping the building of tuples x, y and z

```
diffs = [curr-prev for curr, prev in izip(islice(y, 1, None), islice(y, len(y)-1))]
max_diff = max(diffs)
Z = y[diffs.index(max_diff)+1]
```